# WPF Build should fail if StaticResource is missing

Tags: wpf, xaml, msbuild

is it possible to configure msbuild to fail if there is any StaticResource in my WPF Application XAML that cannot be found?

Comment: Have you tried “Treat warnings as errors”? It should trigger a compilation warning in this case.

Comment: Yes my projects are configured to handle all warnings as errors. It compiles anyways

Comment: It gives an error rather than a warning, but it's from the designer. If you don't have a window with such an error open in the designer then you get no error or warning in your errorlist. Even when you build.I don't think such things are checked by msbuild. You're best ensuring all resources will be present at design time so you see and fix problems there and then.